# PHP User management class

Tags: php, object-oriented, authentication, pdo, session

Here is my code for a class that is responsible for managing some common users task like registration, login and logout. It implements also a sub class that can be used to check the session of a logged in user. I've tested it and works fine, but I will improve it as soon as I can. Any suggestion on security improvements are appreciated.

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

Interface UserInterface{

  public function createUser(array $args);
  public function loginUser(array $args);
  public function logoutUser();

}


class User Implements UserInterface{

    private $db;

    private $stmt;

    private $email;

    private $username;

    private $password;

    private $id;

    private $sessioncode;

    private $args;


    /*
    * @param $db must be a PDO instance
    *
    */
    public function __construct(\PDO $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    /*
    * @param $args must be a key/value array
    *
    */
    public function createUser(array $args){

        if($this->checkEmail($args['email'])){
            #header("HTTP/1.1 400 Email already exsist");
            #http_response_code(400);
            echo 'Email address already exsist.';
        }
        elseif($this->checkUsername($args['username'])){
            #header("HTTP/1.1 400 Username already exsist");
            #http_response_code(400);
            echo 'Username already exsist.';
        }
        else {
            $this->password = password_hash($args['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO _users (email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ? )');
              if($stmt->execute(array($args['email'],$args['username'],$this->password))){
                echo 'Account successful created';
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    * @param $args must be a key/value array
    *
    */
    public function loginUser(array $args){

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM _users WHERE username = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($args['username']));
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                if(count($result) > 0 && password_verify($args['password'], $result->password)){
                  UserSessionHelper::setSession($result->username, $result->id);
                    #header('HTTP/1.1 200');
                    echo 'Logged in';
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Wrong username or password';
                    #header('HTTP/1.1 400');
                }
    }

    /*
    * This method wehn called will logout an user
    *
    */
    public function logoutUser(){
        UserSessionHelper::unsetSession();
        header('HTTP/1.1 200');
        #header('Location: ');
        #echo 'Logged out';
    }

    /*
    * @param $email is a key part of the $args array;
    * This method will check if a given email is already registered.
    */
    private function checkEmail($email){

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT email FROM _users WHERE email = ?');
            $stmt->execute(array($email));
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
              if(count($result) > 0){
                return true;
              }
    }

    /*
    * @param $username is a key part of the $args array;
    * This method will check if a given username is already registered.
    */
    private function checkUsername($username){

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT username FROM _users WHERE username = ?');
            $stmt->execute(array($username));
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
              if(count($result) > 0){
                return true;
              }
    }

}

interface UserSessionHelperInterface{

  public static function unsetSession();
  public static function setSession(string $username, int $user_id);
  public static function validateSessionID(string $session_id, string $session_hash);

}

class UserSessionHelper implements UserSessionHelperInterface{

    private $session_hash;
    private $username;
    private $user_id;

    /*
    * @params $username must be a string, $user_id must be an integer.
    * This method will register the $_SESSION variables when an user login.
    */
    public static function setSession(string $username,int $user_id){

        $_SESSION['session_'] = self::sessionHash();
        $_SESSION['id_'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['username_'] = $username;
        return true;
    }

    /*
    * @param
    * This method will remove all $_SESSION data wehn an user logout.
    */
    public static function unsetSession(){

        session_destroy();
        session_unset();
    }

    /*
    * @params $session_id must be a valid string, $session_hash must be a valid string.
    * This method will check for valid session credentials when an user is logged in.
    */
    public static function validateSessionID(string $session_id,string $session_hash){

        $computed_session_hash = hash('sha384', $session_id);

          if(!preg_match('/^[-,a-zA-Z0-9]{1,128}$/', $session_id) > 0){
              #return header('HTTP/1.1 403');
          }
          elseif(!hash_equals($computed_session_hash, $session_hash)){
              #return header('HTTP/1.1 403');
          }
          else{
              return true;
          }
    }

    /*
    * This method is responsable to hash the regenerated session id, then return it
    *
    */
    private function sessionHash(){

        session_regenerate_id();
        $session_hash = hash('sha384', session_id());
        return $session_hash;
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Would `validateSessionID()` not get `$session_id` and `$session_hash` from `session_id()` and `$_SESSION['session_']`? Why have them as method arguments, if this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

- For session management, you might want to take a look at [`SessionHandlerInterface`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php). Generally, your class can handle it all, but further on - you can set custom session data storage, like Memcache or Redis.
- It seems like you're using `php7`(param typehints), but no return types. Consider doing that too. For instance, `UserSessionHelper::sessionHash` can be declared as `function sessionHash() : string`
- Class `User` sounds like a model class, while it's actually kind of a repository/manager. Consider re-naming.
- It is considered a good practice to separate the resource handler logic and business logic, e.g. queries for DB and the user management. What I would do, is move the DB logic to a separate class, `UserStore`, for instance,

  ```
   class UserStore {
      public function isEmailUnique(string $email) : bool {
          // check in DB
      }

      public function isEmailUnique(string $username) : bool {
          // check in DB
      }

      public function create($email, $username, $password): UserModel {

      }
   }
  ```

  and inject it to `User` class. So that the `UserManager` class could looks something like this:

  ```
  class UserManager {

      /**
       * @var UserStore
       */
      protected $store;

      public function __construct(UserStore $store) {
          $this-store = $store;
      }

      /**
       * @param array $args
       * @return UserModel
       */
      public function createUser(array $args): UserModel {
          if (!$this->store->isEmailUnique($args['email'])) {
              throw new \LogicException('Email address already exsist');
          }

          if (!$this->store->isUsernameUnique($args['username'])) {
              throw new \LogicException('Username is already taken.');
          }

          return $this->store->create(
              $args['email'], 
              $args['username'], 
              password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
          );
      }
   }
  ```

Hope that helps.